# Approach on solving a word problem based on cyclic geometry

Tags: geometry, circles, plane-geometry

Here is the question - Two chords AB and CD of a circle with centre O , Intersect each other at P. If angle AOD = 100 and angle BOC= 70. Find value of angle APC.

Now I know how to solve this kind of problems ( See the image ) but only when I follow a specific approach , that is to take the 4 points across the circle.  If I try to solve this problem by taking points on the same side of circle. I can't solve it. Can anyone please tell me how to solve it by that method. ( See attach image for better understanding) 
[image: Solution]

Comment: Which points do you include as the 'same side of the circle'?

Comment: Please try a better picture. AB seems to pass through the center O of the circle, which is painted in hurry. It is hard to understand what you did, please use mathjax and post explicitly the computations done.

Answer (score 1):

I like the following way.

Since $\widehat{AD}=100^{\circ},$  we obtain:
$$\widehat {DB}=180^{\circ}-100^{\circ}=80^{\circ}.$$
Also, $$\widehat{AC}=180^{\circ}-70^{\circ}=110^{\circ}.$$
Ids est, $$\measuredangle APC=\frac{1}{2}(80^{\circ}+110^{\circ})=95^{\circ}.$$